# How Google is getting the Current Location without user permission

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

i just type current location and it detect the street. is there any way to detect like this from google web service or any other way?
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGlBw.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

That's probably a low accuracy estimate based on the outbound IP of your computer

Comment: Yes, but i need that info, its usefull. how to get that?

Comment: There are free and commercial services that give you that information: just google "where is my ip" and you will get a list of services to identify your outbound ip, and then a list of services to get lat/long from a given IP. Google probably has it's own IP/location database

Comment: i tried that but its not showing same spot as google search

Comment: If you want the exact location google gives you, then try google's own api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the IP you receive to an online geolocation service. [Here](http://www.geoplugin.com/quickstart#how_to_geo-localize_your_visitors) is one useful link.

Comment: not showing me correct location, check the screenshot. its different location

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [GeoIP Database](https://geoip-db.com/).

**GeoIP Database** is a free service that keeps track of your visitor's geolocation, based on their IP address.

**Note:**
This is free for small projects. they allow only 1000 calls per day as free.

[***Get Current Location***](https://geoip-db.com/json/)

Comment: not showing me correct location, check the screenshot. its different location

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here after visiting aerisweather.com and noticed they got my location correct without asking for permission. I'm on a desktop PC without GPS nor anything wireless, so AFAIK the only way to legally get the location of this computer is via IP.

Tried a dozen ip to location websites and most of them are 50+ miles off (all showing different lat/long). On iplocation.net there's results of several services, and 1 was correct (eurekAPI) and 1 other was just a couple miles off (ip2location).

I found several other sites with correct location after asking for permission (html5 geolocation api). They could have just gone ahead and get it via my IP.

So, correct location via IP can be done with a database that contains correct IP to lat/long info. Converting lat/long to a location name is the easy part.